# How to catch error inside of promise in which I call a callback?

Tags: node.js

```
let uploadMulterPromise = (upload, req, res, uuid) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) return reject(new Error('Some error after saving file'));
            if (!req.file) return reject(new Error('Can not determine extension'));
            if (!req.file.size) return reject(new Error('Can not determine size'));
            return resolve({
                size: req.file.size,
                link: `https://${process.env.HOST_FOR_MEDIA}:3000/media-file/${uuid}.mp3`
            })
        })
    })
};
```

I have this snippet of code. I want to catch some unpredictable error inside the upload function, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: You can wrap it in `try { } catch` and call `reject` inside of the `catch` block

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What exactly should happen with this error? Should it be rethrown? An exception inside promise constructor would result in rejected promise, no extra actions needed.